# Dynamically change the status of a ProgressBar based on two TextFields

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to change the status of a `ProgressBar` while the user is typing a text on either text fields.

**For example** , the user starts typing on the first `TextView`, the `ProgressBar` should change it's value, if he deletes the text, it should reset to the previous value which **is 30**

```
package com.example.phill.jokes;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Entry extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar pr;

private Handler rHandler = new Handler();
private TextView tv ;
private TextView tv2 ;
private boolean titleboolean;
private boolean jokeboolean;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry);

    pr = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9) ;
    tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6) ;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true)
            {

                android.os.SystemClock.sleep(300);
                rHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pr.setProgress(30);
                        if(tv.getText().toString().matches(""))
                        {
                            titleboolean=true;
                        }
                        else
                            titleboolean=false;
                        if(tv2.getText().toString().matches(""))
                        {
                            jokeboolean=true;
                        }
                        else
                            jokeboolean=false;
                        if(titleboolean)
                        {
                            pr.setProgress(60);
                        }
                        if(jokeboolean)
                        {
                            pr.setProgress(100);
                        }

                    }
                });
                if(titleboolean && jokeboolean)
                    break;
            }
            rHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(titleboolean && jokeboolean){
                        tv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    ;
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
  }
}
```

The value of the `ProgressBar` never changes.
Any Ideas?

Comment: TextViews are supposed to be read only. To capture user input you should be using something like an EditText. Also, with EditText you can add listeners for changes to the input text and move you ProgressBar updates logic into such listeners.

Comment: so is it impossible to move it based on the textview?

Comment: Is the user able to type into the TextView?

Comment: You cannot use TextView for User Input, you need to use `EditText` which also has listener for the purpose you need.

Comment: @DarShan yes i used `EditText` as you can see below, but for some reason the method setProgress() is called only when i edit the second `EditText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain you in detail

```
if(titleboolean && jokeboolean)
                break;
```

when your both text fields clears it calls break statement after that your thread stops running you can achieve this in another way

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
private ProgressBar pr;

private EditText tv;
private EditText tv2;
private boolean titleboolean;
private boolean jokeboolean;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    pr=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv2);


    TextView tV = new TextView(this); 
    tV.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence 
  s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, 
    int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            setProgress();

        }
    });
    tv2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence 
 s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, 
int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            setProgress();

        }
    });
}

public void setProgress() {
    pr.setProgress(30);
    if (tv.getText().toString().matches("")) {
        titleboolean = true;
    } else
        titleboolean = false;
    if (tv2.getText().toString().matches("")) {
        jokeboolean = true;
    } else
        jokeboolean = false;
    if (titleboolean) {
        pr.setProgress(60);
    }
        if (jokeboolean) {
            pr.setProgress(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works although when it starts the activity, the `ProgressBar` is at 0 when  i edit the 1st `EditView`it goes to 30, then i edit the second it goes to 60 and if i delete the text it goes to 100

Comment: basically when it starts, it shoud be 30, after the title is completed should go to 60 and if the second `EditView` is completed as well should go to 100. Also it has to work the other way around, if one those two is completed should go to 60 etc(i have to fix the cases).
Although the method you suggested works perfectly, thank you

Comment: yes you can create your own logic of progress bar in setProgress function

Comment: although something is not working for the first `EditView` the second works perfectly but not the first

Answer (score 0):

Use `EditText` instead `TextView` with `TextChangedListener`.

1. `TextView` does not allow to type text.
2. Also infinite cycle with pauses is bad approach, use `EditText.addTextChangedListener` to handle text after it have changed